after removing BSPWM all applications open on half of screen
I usually use a minimal openbox based DE (Debian 12). I tried BSPWM a while ago and then decided to go back to openbox. However, after completely removing BSPWM and its config files, I found that applications cannot be maximized to full screen. I can manually expand them with the mouse, but when I click the "maximize" button, all applications are expanded to exactly half the screen. I deleted the entire ~/.cache folder, but it does not help.
Please help
